# UIImagePickerController video with allowEditing = YES 'Use' button not clickable

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm capturing a video that has a 1 minute maxDuration with allowsEditing = YES.

Randomly it freezes when it gets to the video editing step where you have the trim, play, and use buttons. The trim menu doesn't appear and tapping the use button doesn't do anything.

There doesn't seem to be a pattern related to the freezes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UIImagePickerController has a known memory leak which causes freezing or crashing due to low memory, this is a known bug and it has been there almost from the start. There are various ways in which to help reduce the effect of this leak such as making sure you only allocate the UIImagePickerController once in your app and always use the same instance of it. If you google the UIImagePickerController memory leak you will find lots of articles on how to deal with this issues.

Hope this helps!